# Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to insert/update my table using the values in the `grid`

[image]

Given below is the code I'm using to get the `productId` in the grid:

```
Dim prodId = From row As DataRow _
             In grdSale.Rows _
             Where row.Item(0).ToString <> "" _
             Select row.Item(0)
```

I am getting `productid` correctly. Given below is the code to get the value in `QTY` column with respect to the `productId`:

```
For Each id As Long In prodId

    Dim intpdt As Long
    intpdt = id

    intQty = (From row As DataRow In grdSale.Rows Where _
              row.Item(0).Equals(intpdt) _
              Select row.Item("QTY")).FirstOrDefault()

Next
```

In `intQty` I am getting `0` but it should be `10` or `12` as you can see in the `QTY` column in the grid (`Enumeration yielded no results`).

Where am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you convert `row.Item(0)` to a `long` in your query?

Comment: Don't know, but I would strongly recommend to build logic on the data, not on the data in the grid. So query the source data of `grdSale.Rows`.

Comment: Is `grdSale` a `GridView`/`DataGridView` or a `DataTable`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `grdSale` is [`C1TrueDBGrid`](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/TrueDBGridWinForms/) rows are datarowCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this and see if you get the result you expected:

```
intQty = _
( _
    From row As DataRow In grdSale.Rows Where _
    CLng(row.Item(0)) = intpdt _
    Select CInt(row.Item("QTY")) _
).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Error: `CInt(row.Item("QTY")).FirstOrDefault())` -> `FirstOrDefault is not a member of integer`

Comment: @hector - You've typed it in incorrectly. You have missed a bracket. There are three closing brackets after "QTY", not two.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what causes your issue, but you should use the `Field` extension method since it is strongly typed and supports nullable types. I also don't understand why you need the additional loop and query to find the quantity of each product. This should do both:

```
Dim prodQTYs = From row In grdSale.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)()
               Let ProductID = row.Field(Of String)("ProductId")
               Let Quantity = row.Field(Of Long)("QTY")
               Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProductID)
               Select New With {.ProductID = ProductID, .Quantity = Quantity}
```

Change the types to the appropriate ones.

Output:

```
For Each prodInfo In prodQTYs
    Console.WriteLine("Product:{0} Quantity:{1}", prodInfo.ProductID, prodInfo.Quantity)
Next
```